# PHP Connect to MS SQL Database

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-server-2000, remote-access

I have a website locally hosted on my computer. My server is using PHP 5.6.21.  I am trying to connect to a SQL Database on another computer Microsoft SQL Server 2000.

I have installed the PHP extensions,  PHP_sqlsrv_56_ts and PHP_sqlsrv_56_nts.  I have enabled them in the php.ini:
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

I have tried to connect using this:

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress, 1542"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

And I tried using this:

```
<?php 

$connection_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=<Hector\SQLEXPRESS>;DATABASE=tempdb'; 
$user = 'sqltestclient';
$pass = 'paSSword';
$connection = odbc_connect( $connection_string, $user, $pass ) or die("Unable to connect to server");
echo $connection.' '.$user.' '.$pass;
?>
```

But neither work, the top wont load the page and the bottom just sasys unable to connect.

Im not sure what Im doing wrong

Comment: Connection strings with SQL Server can be problematic.  They may be the most likely source of trouble here.  https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2000/  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722656(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sql Server 2000 is way past end of life. It no longer gets any patches, even for critical security issues, and hasn't for some time now. Continuing to use it is highly irresponsible. Upgrading this server is job 1.

Comment: Joel.  SQL Server 2000 is old???...Hmm thanks for stating the obvious.  Im looking for assistance with the server I am currently using not a lecture.  .. Obviously a new server is ideal. If you have nothing helpful to say about the question at hand, please save your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using the information from this link.
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/access-microsoft-sql-server-2000-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help:

```
$serverName = "SERVER\\NAME"; 
$connInfo = array("Database"=>"stockdata");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connInfo);
if($conn){
 $sql  = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
 $res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);   

 $arr = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC); 

 print_r($arr);



}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

If you are using  Windows Authentication no need to provide credentials ,otherwise you will get exception